# How to remove all keychain entries an app created from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, keychain

It seems that when an app creates keychain entries, these entries remain in the keychain even after the app is deleted.

Afaik this behaviour was changed in ios11.3 beta, but the change was reverted for the release candidate and afaik in the latest iOS it’s still the case that if an appcreates a keychain entry, this entry persists even after deleting the app from the phone.

How can I delete all keychain entries an app created for good?

Comment: you mean passwords ?

Comment: No I mean any kind of entry into the keychain. Apps can store arbitrary data in the keychain and use it as a kind of encrypted, persistent data store. This data store is not emptied on deletion of the app and as such data stored in this way persists across re-installs of an app.

Comment: This is still an issue in 2023 and are being used by companies to track users across both different apps and installs. How can Apple allow this considering their commitment to privacy???